# Apache Camel Context starting but not finding routes

Tags: routes, apache-camel

I am currently trying to implement apace camel spring based routing into my project and am coming across some issues. I am able to get the CamelContext to automatically start when I run my program but I keep getting the messsage:

Total 0 routes, of which 0 is started.
Apache Camel 2.6.0 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 0.790 seconds

This is showing up in the logging.

I will post the "camel-context" and maybe someone can point to where I am going astray. I am lost at the moment and am really trying to get a handle on this technology because it does sound pretty powerful. I hope this is an easy fix! Let me know if you need anything else.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<spring:beans xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:alch="http://service.alchemy.kobie.com/"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans classpath:META-INF/spring/spring-beans.xsd 
    http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring classpath:META-INF/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

<!-- load properties -->
<spring:bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <spring:property name="locations" value="file:backend.properties" />
</spring:bean>

<spring:bean id="properties"
    class="org.apache.camel.component.properties.PropertiesComponent">
    <spring:property name="location" value="file:backend.properties" />
</spring:bean>

<spring:bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" 
    class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <spring:property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?useLocalHost=true" />
</spring:bean>

<spring:bean id="pooledConnectionFactory" 
    class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory">
    <spring:property name="maxConnections" value="8" />
    <spring:property name="maximumActive" value="500" />
    <spring:property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
</spring:bean>

<spring:bean id="jmsConfig" 
    class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
    <spring:property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledConnectionFactory"/>
    <spring:property name="transacted" value="false"/>
    <spring:property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1"/>
</spring:bean>

<spring:bean id="activemq" 
    class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <spring:property name="configuration" ref="jmsConfig"/>
</spring:bean>

<!-- Loaded Beans -->

<spring:bean id="ExactTargetBean" class="com.backend.trigger.TargetBean" /> 
<spring:bean id="TriggerEmailRequestBean" class="com.requests.TriggerEmailRequest" />


<!-- Camel configuration -->

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="genericMessageHandler" streamCache="true">
        <from uri = "activemq:topic:Test.topic"/>
        <multicast>  
            <to uri = "TargetIntegration" />
        </multicast>
    </route>
     <route>
        <from uri="TargetIntegration" />
            <setProperty propertyName="apiuser">
                <simple>${properties:et.username}</simple>
            </setProperty>
            <setProperty propertyName="password">
                <simple>${properties:et.password}</simple>
            </setProperty>
            <setProperty propertyName="triggerName">
                <constant>WelcomeEmail</constant>
            </setProperty>
            <setProperty propertyName="email">
                <constant>patrick@test.com</constant>
            </setProperty>
            <setProperty propertyName="firstName">
                <constant>Patrick</constant>
            </setProperty>
            <setProperty propertyName="lastName">
                <constant>Archambeau</constant>
            </setProperty>
        <to uri = "xslt:xslt/target-integration.xsl" />
        <log message="Transformed Message : ${in.body}" />

        <setBody>
            <simple>qf=xml&amp;xml=${in.body}</simple>
        </setBody>
        <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod">
            <constant>POST</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <setHeader headerName="Content-type">
            <constant>application/x-www-form-urlencoded</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <setHeader headerName="Connection">
            <simple>close</simple>
        </setHeader>
        <log message="Transformed Message : ${in.body}" />
        <to uri = "{{et.integration.url}}" />
        <log message="Transformed Message : ${in.body}" />
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

Comment: First, you are using a rather old version of Camel, is it the same in the latest? Also, do you get any other issues? Such as errors trying to connect with ActiveMQ or anything? It seems wierd otherwise.

Comment: I have no issues connecting to activemq, I am able to start it up on my local machine and access the portal where you can add topics/set up queues/post messages to queues etc. I will try updating all of my jars and see if that fixes the problem.